# Why do gifs cause Chrome to layout the whole document at each frame?

Tags: performance, dom, browser

I've been trying to find/prevent why my page is freezing at Firefox, I'm using Chrome's Developer Timeline to track the layouts and paints (freezing doesn't occur at Chrome, a huge issue at Firefox with ~300 UI tiles on the page)

It's understandable that gifs cause paints at each frame (a much much larger paint area than the gif itself, unfortunately) - however I don't understand why Chrome reports a "whole document" layout before each frame - since the size of the gif is constant, it should only cause paints in my opinion

I'm guessing these "whole document" layouts are causing firefox to freeze when there are many elements on the document

(I've researched reflows/layouts, repaints in depth, however none of the articles cover gifs, by looking at the timeline, I would say gifs are major resource hogs)

Answer (score 0):

After more careful inspection and testing, I was able to prevent full document layouts by utilizing a gif container div, such as:

```
<div style="position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 10px; width: 45px; height: 15px; overflow: hidden">
    <img src="/gif_url" style="vertical-align: top"/>
</div>
```

The issue was probably occurring because of the gif's positioning, happens with both float:right and position: absolute, even when the img element has fixed height and width of it's own (might happen with other positioning styles too)

I didn't dive into the issue too deeply to see what triggers the full document layouts and what not, however, it seems like a good idea to wrap every gif with a blocker div to be sure that browsers calculate partial layouts (I'm guessing there might be a combination of styles that might be able to achieve this inline, but I haven't pushed it yet)

**- EDIT (after much inspection) -**

It turns out the root cause is Bootstrap 2.3.2's default "max-width: 100%" style for img's

Removing that definition seized layouts caused by gifs

If there is going to be even one gif on the page, that style should definitely be removed / cancelled - otherwise at each gif frame the whole document is being laid out by the browser (chrome in this case, possibly others too)

Comment: it was also interesting to observe that such a small gif, a not so important part of the page and UI, could cause such disruption. I'm glad I finally started utilizing the Chrome Timeline, opened up a new world for me